# C++0x threads question

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, c++11

I have a question regarding the c++0x standard threads.Can they be used at the moment (in vc++ 2010)? I see people providing tutorials on how to use them, but im a bit confused if the library can actually be used atm. I know you can use things like "auto" in vc++, so i thought i'd ask :. Every time i try and use the new threads, i get errors when trying to include them. This makes me think the answer to my question is "No", but wtf is up with the tutorials+other people using them!?

If not, can someone point me in the right direction? I just want to learn about threads, and not have to learn worry about platforms :.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No standard threading exists in VC++ 2010.  Maybe you should try the Boost threads library; the standard threading library is based off it so migration will likely be very easy once VC++ does support standard threading.

As for other people writing tutorials about them, VC++ is one compiler among many, and others may be quicker to support the new standard.

Answer (score 1):

> With the [just::thread C++](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/) Standard
>   Thread Library implementation, you can
>   start using the C++0x thread library
>   today ...

http://www.stdthread.co.uk/

Note that the library is *not* free.